# Network not getting created as '--attachable' in standalone swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have set up a docker swarm referencing to [Docker Documentation - Create Swarm cluster](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/#step-5-create-swarm-cluster).

I started a consul, a manager, and a node. When I'm trying to create a network for my future containers with command:

```
docker -H :4000 network create --attachable --driver overlay hyp-net
```

I get the error stating saying:

> "--attachable" requires API version 1.25, but the Docker daemon API version is 1.24

[image: error image]

When I check the version of my swarm manager I see the docker API version downgraded from 1.30 to 1.24. Its not so for my host or the consul or the node, just downgraded for swarm manager:

[image: swarm version details]

So I can't seem to control the manager downgrading itself, and create an overlay network on it. What am I missing? Tried this two times on two separate machines with docker versions:

- 17.09.1-ce
- 17.06.0-ce.

Comment: Welcome to SO! First, please avoid posting screenshots of terminal output. It is really hard for others,  because instead of a simple copy and paste of the text, everyone has to retype the text. Thus, it is better to simply copy and paste the output and put it into a code environment. If you need more help with this, click on the question mark or have a look at the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Now back to your question: Any chance you used docker-machine for setting up the swarm? If so, did you already tried to update your docker version by [`docker-machine upgrade default`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/upgrade/)?

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason: **user is not part of `docker` group**.

Very similar error happends with `docker system prune`, it does not clearly state the error, instead giving ambiguous `"container prune" requires API version 1.25, but the Docker daemon API version is 1.24` error